# Why can't I use '!checked' to toggle the checked property of my checkbox in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have some state in my component that holds the value of my checkbox element. I need to update the state as well as the UI everytime the checkbox is clicked. My Question is why I can't use `!clicked` like this

```
function handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
        console.log(checked)
        setFormData(prevState => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                [name]: type === "checkbox" ? !checked : value
            }
        })
        console.log(checked)
    }
```

this doesn't work in updating the state or the UI. Instead I have to change it to `checked` to see the UI/State update. From my understanding the `checked` property comes from the targeted `event`. Which is this checkbox.

```
<input
    id="okayToEmail"
    type="checkbox"
    checked={formData.hasJoined}
    name="hasJoined"
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

the value for the `checked` property or attribute comes from the state here.

```
const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
     email: "",
     password: "",
     confirmedPassword: "",
     hasJoined: true
})
```

you can see the `checked` property equates to a boolean. So why can't I use `!checked`?? How is the UI toggling back and forth when I'm giving it the original value of `checked`?? This hurts my brain. Can you please explain this in lamen terms. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`event.target.checked` is the latest checkbox value, you don't need to negate that, this should work:

```
return {
  ...prevState,
  [name]: type === "checkbox" ? checked : value,
};
```

or you can negate from the `prevState`:

```
return {
  ...prevState,
  [name]: type === "checkbox" ? !prevState.hasJoined : value,
};
```

Comment: Even if i don't "need" to do that, why does it not work? shouldn't the check box still alternate whatever value is stored in that property? If the value is coming from the state and its set to `false` then the opposite of that is `true` and vice versa. However logging the checked property with `!checked` in the ternary shows the value never changing in state. Therefore it doesn't change in the UI. I appreciate the help but I'm still confused. You might need to really dumb down the answer, I'm a novice.

Comment: I think you're confusing over the fact that `checked` is from the event object, not from your state, in your situation, the checkbox is checked initially, as the `input` is bind to the state's `hasJoined` property, and when you click it, the value you get from `e.target.checked` is `false`, and when you negate that, you get `true`, that's why you don't need to negate that, it's already a negative value given to you, and vice versa